# Concerned I can smell gas at the other end of the house when parents turn on their new gas oven - is it safe?

Tags: oven, natural-gas

My parents just bought a new gas range + oven and had it installed.  Up to this point, they used an electric range.  Whenever they turn on the oven for any reason, there is a gas smell and the natural gas sensor installed reads an increase from 0 to 2.  After about 5 minutes the smell goes away and the gas sensor goings down.

**The problem - I can smell gas at the other end of the house when they turn on the oven.**  The house is likely 75 feet or more in length.  I'm not the only person who noticed either.  Other family members have noticed this too.  It disappears in about 5 minutes, but my concern is the fact I can distinctly smell gas from so far away.

I understand it's normal to smell gas right after you turn on the oven since you've just opened the valve and let gas in.  My concern is I can smell it on the other side of the house.  We had the installer come out and take a look.  **He said everything was fine and it was normal to be able to smell gas when in use - even at the other end of the house.  Is it normal and safe to smell gas like this?**

**EDIT More Info**

[It's a GE 5-burner](https://www.lowes.com/pd/GE-5-Burners-5-cu-ft-Self-Cleaning-Convection-Freestanding-Gas-Range-Fingerprint-Resistant-Slate-Common-30-in-Actual-30-in/1003242954?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-vf-_-app-_-ggl-_-SS_APP_Appliances_VF-GE-_-1003242954-_-online-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6NOPBhCPARIsAHAy2zDy8Y_Z9zt4LOC_N-5qTeFEAe5qLzujOkrNM-pDZS2XSMPtXmEf1QEaAnDYEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).  Currently, there is no hood to the outside, just a microwave with a fan above it.  My parents are looking to get a vented hood installed to see if that will fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe I'll call my gas company and order an in-house inspection.

Comment: Get a professional - they have gas sniffers and can find the leak or source.

Comment: i vote for perfectly normal and safe. a whiff across a well circulated house is no problem, when you have a real leak problem the smell is overwhelming (don't ask how i found that out). It also goes away soon, on it's own, indicating it's just a startup issue. Ovens take a while to ignite, so I doubt it can be turned on and off fast enough to leak enough gas to cause any problem to safety or health, but it does sound annoying if you've got a sensitive sniffer.

Comment: It's probably not dangerous, but certainly worth looking into. I could be incomplete combustion initially.  How the odor (exhaust?) gets into the other end of the house is troublesome. Is there a hood vent over the stove?  Where is it vented to? Any cold air returns for a forced air furnace near the kitchen?   So, let us know more details...make and model of the range would help a lot.

Comment: By all means get ideas and suggestions, but considering your circumstances (75ft, new stove, etc) your ultimate question "is it safe?" I believe should not and cannot be answered here.